# ContourPlot3D, grid of cylinders

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make a 3D contour plot that looks like a grid of cylinders to represent the Fermi surface of a metal, like below:

[image: Fermi surface]

I have no problem generating something that kind of looks like it.

[image: nodal surface]

(`Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z] == 0`). (This shows multiple unit cells.)

I need it to be more cylindrical, though. I need to also later plot cross-sections of this for planes at different heights, so it is more than just wanting the accurate figure.

I think this is tricky because it is not well-suited to either cylindrical coordinates or spherical coordinates. I was thinking that I could just create three cylinders at right angles to each other and superimpose them, but I can't figure out a way to make the equation for cylinders.

Any help on this would be great!

Comment: Do you want real cylinders or "smoothed cylinders" like the approaches with ```Cos```?
Should the interior be hollow or filled?

Comment: The "real cylinders" approach would correspond to Michael's and my answer, while cvgmt's answer uses a [nodal surface](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0009-2614(00)01418-4) approximation.

Comment: Another approach would be to use `Cylinder` and `RegionUnion` to construct a single `Region` object

Comment: @J.M. I think that the nodal surface approximation is actually closer to the physical situation that I am modeling (Fermi surface), but your answer is also very useful.  I can't seem, however, to make the cross-sections without there being little gaps in the circles using your approach (I think because of the `Round[]` function).

Comment: @Nick, are you using the current version in my answer? Indeed, the previous formulation of my answer had those artifacts, but I do not believe the current one does.

Answer (score 21):

Maybe add some perturbed term  such as `Cos[x]*Cos[y]*Cos[z]` or `Cos[x]*Cos[y]+Cos[y]*Cos[z]+Cos[z]*Cos[x]` to `Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z]`.

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z] - 1.5 Cos[x] Cos[y] Cos[z] == 1.5, {x, -9, 
  9}, {y, -9, 9}, {z, -9, 9}, ContourStyle -> FaceForm[Orange, Cyan], 
 Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking!

Answer (score 13):

cvgmt had the right idea to use a periodic function. Using a technique similar to what I did [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159096), here is how to use `Round[]` (for periodicity) with `Max[]` (as a stand-in for Boolean OR):

```
With[{c = 1, r = 1/4}, 
     ContourPlot3D[Max[r^2 - (x - Round[x, c])^2 - (y - Round[y, c])^2, 
                       r^2 - (y - Round[y, c])^2 - (z - Round[z, c])^2, 
                       r^2 - (z - Round[z, c])^2 - (x - Round[x, c])^2] == 0,
                   {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}, {z, -3/2, 3/2}]]
```

[image: cylinders]

You'd need to be prepared to crank up `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` for this approach (with the concomitant increase in memory requirements).

---

A variation of this theme is to replace `Max[]` with a [smooth version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_maximum) like [$\log$-sum-$\exp$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp):

```
With[{c = 1, r = 1/4, k = 30},
     ContourPlot3D[Log[Total[
                   Exp[k {r^2 - (x - Round[x, c])^2 - (y - Round[y, c])^2, 
                          r^2 - (y - Round[y, c])^2 - (z - Round[z, c])^2, 
                          r^2 - (z - Round[z, c])^2 - (x - Round[x, c])^2}]]]/k == 0,
                   {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}, {z, -3/2, 3/2}]]
```

[image: smoothmax connection of cylinders]

Answer (score 8):

This can perhaps be generalized easiliy to other constraints. The equation of a cylinder in the z-direction can be written as a function that evaluates to zero.
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2&=r^2\\
f_Z(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-r^2&=0
\end{align}
So to get an intersection of three cylinders you just multiply three of these functions together:

```
range = 3;
r = 1;
ContourPlot3D[
   (x^2 + y^2 - r^2) (z^2 + y^2 - r^2) (z^2 + x^2 - r^2) == 0,
      {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, range}, {z, -range, range}   
]
```

[image]

The nice thing is you can easily smooth this out by taking a contour slightly above zero.

```
ContourPlot3D[
   (x^2 + y^2 - r^2) (z^2 + y^2 - r^2) (z^2 + x^2 - r^2) == 0.05,
      {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, range}, {z, -range, range}   
]
```

[image]

You can make this periodic by replacing `x -> Sin[x]` (same for $y,z$) or by replacing
`x -> Mod[x, period, - period/2]`. `Sin[x]` seems to work faster but you won't get perfect cylinders.

```
range = 5;
r = .5;
ContourPlot3D[(Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2 - r^2) (Sin[z]^2 + Sin[y]^2 - 
     r^2) (Sin[x]^2 + Sin[z]^2 - r^2) == .005, {x, -range, 
  range}, {y, -range, range}, {z, -range, range}]
```

[image]

Comment: In my answer, I originally used multiplication (AND) instead of `Max[]` (OR), but the resulting surface had blemishes for some reason, which is why I switched to the current formulation.

Comment: @J.M. Yes I think our answers nicely complement each other.

Answer (score 6):

Another way, if you want cylinders:

```
ddd = Min@Table[
    RegionDistance[
      InfiniteLine[{Insert[{a, b}, 0, j], Insert[{a, b}, 1, j]}]]
      [{x, y, z}],
    {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {j, 3}
    ];

ContourPlot3D[ddd == 1/4 // Evaluate,
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is helpful

```
ContourPlot3D[{
  (x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 1,
  (x + 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 == 1,
  (x - 2)^2 + (y + 2)^2 == 1,
  (x + 2)^2 + (y + 2)^2 == 1,
  
  (x - 2)^2 + (z - 2)^2 == 1,
  (x + 2)^2 + (z - 2)^2 == 1,
  (x - 2)^2 + (z + 2)^2 == 1,
  (x + 2)^2 + (z + 2)^2 == 1,
  
  (y - 2)^2 + (z - 2)^2 == 1,
  (y + 2)^2 + (z - 2)^2 == 1,
  (y - 2)^2 + (z + 2)^2 == 1,
  (y + 2)^2 + (z + 2)^2 == 1
  }, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}
 ]
```

There are probably cleverer ways to create the cylinders, depending on what you want to do with them.

[image]

If this does not need to be a contour plot, have a look at the `Cylinder[]` function.

Comment: Is there a way to make the grid of cylinders into a single object? When I take cross-sections it treats them all as separate, but I need it to act like a unit.

Answer (score 5):

Just to show how to do this without `ContourPlot3D` and instead with `Region` objects

```
RegionUnion[
 Sequence @@ Table[
   RegionUnion[
     Cylinder[{{-1, 0, n}, {1, 0, n}}, .2],
     Cylinder[{{0, -1, n}, {0, 1, n}}, .2]
     ] // Region,
   {n, -1, 1}
   ],
 Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}, .2]
 ]
```

[image]

Or if you just want the boundary

```
tubeboundary = RegionUnion[
 Sequence @@ Table[
   RegionUnion[
     RegionBoundary@Cylinder[{{-1, 0, n}, {1, 0, n}}, .2],
     RegionBoundary@Cylinder[{{0, -1, n}, {0, 1, n}}, .2]
     ] // Region,
   {n, -1, 1}
   ],
 RegionBoundary@Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}, .2]
 ]
```

and this allows you to get a function for the surface

```
tubeboundary // RegionMember

RegionMemberFunction[
 BooleanRegion[#1 || #2 || #3 || #4 || #5 || #6 || #7 & , {RegionBoundary[
    Cylinder[{{-1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, -1}}, 0.2]], 
   RegionBoundary[Cylinder[{{0, -1, -1}, {0, 1, -1}}, 0.2]], 
   RegionBoundary[Cylinder[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 0.2]], << 2 >>, 
   RegionBoundary[Cylinder[{{<< 3 >>}, {<< 3 >>}}, 0.2]], 
   RegionBoundary[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}, 0.2]]}], <>]
```

Answer (score 4):

So, one thing you can do here is note that the equation for a cylinder extending along the z-axis is $x^2+y^2=0$, or $x^2+y^2\leq0$ for a solid cylinder. That is, it's the equation for a circle that ignores one of the axes! The other two just choose different axes to ignore. As such

```
RegionPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 <= 1, y^2 + z^2 <= 1, z^2 + x^2 <= 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

gets you the three cylinders:

[image: 3 cylinders along each of the 3 cardinal axes of different colors]

You can change the colors and styling with the options of `RegionPlot3D`:

```
RegionPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 <= 1, y^2 + z^2 <= 1, z^2 + x^2 <= 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
             PlotStyle -> {Directive[Magenta, Opacity[0.5]], Directive[Cyan, Opacity[0.5]], Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]]}, 
             Mesh -> False]
```

[image: Transparent cylinders]

Importantly, you can get cross sections by `And`-ing (`&&`) these conditions with the condition for being below a plane. Consider the plane specified by $x+y-2z=0$; we have

```
RegionPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && x + y + z/2 >= 0, 
              y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && x + y + z/2 >= 0, 
              z^2 + x^2 <= 1 && x + y + z/2 >= 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
             PlotStyle -> {Directive[Magenta, Opacity[0.5]], Directive[Cyan, Opacity[0.5]], Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]]}, 
             Mesh -> False,
             PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Note that we also had to set `PlotPoints` to a higher number to get something that looks nice! You could make it even higher to make it look better.

[image: cross section]

(Now, you might be wondering: how do I automate this to produce a grid? And is the `Cylinder` graphics primitive better? Maybe. I'll try to update this answer when I have a chance later!)

Answer (score 1):

And yet another parameterization:

```
fun = E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2 + E^-(y^2 + z^2)^2 + E^-(x^2 + z^2)^2;

n = 4;

ContourPlot3D[fun == 0.1, {x, -n, n}, {y, -n, n}, {z, -n, n}, 
 PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm @ fun]
```

[image]

Comment: Basically the log-sum-exp approach, yes.