# PeriodicInterpolation does not work in ElementMeshInterpolation

Tags: interpolation, finite-element-method, mesh

I want to use `ElementMeshInterpolation` to generate interpolation function with periodic boundary condition.

I use below data as an example

```
data=Flatten[Table[{i,j,Sin[i+j]},{i,0,2\[Pi],2\[Pi]/50},{j,0,2\[Pi],2\[Pi]/50}],1];
ListContourPlot[data]
```

which gives

[image]

This data is periodic along x and y direction.

**Using Interpolation**

```
f = Interpolation[data, PeriodicInterpolation -> True];
{ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
 ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 4 \[Pi]}]}
```

gives

[image]

We can see the Interpolation function is fine with periodic condition as wanted.

**using ElementMeshInterpolation**

Though `Interpolation` works fine for this data set. But Interpolation has problem that it frequently run into ["femimq" problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77786/4742). So `ElementMeshInterpolation` on a refined mesh is necessary sometimes.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[data[[;; , 1 ;; 2]]];
f = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, data[[;; , -1]], 
   PeriodicInterpolation -> {True, True}];
{ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
 ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 4 \[Pi]}]}
```

this gives

[image]

You see the generated Interpolation function has no periodicity.

**using ListInterpolation**

mesh can also be used in `ListInterpolation`

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[data[[;; , 1 ;; 2]]];
f = ListInterpolation[data[[;; , -1]], mesh, 
   PeriodicInterpolation -> {True, True}];
{ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
 ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 4 \[Pi]}]}
```

but this gives the same result as `ElementMeshInterpolation`.

**So the question is how to correctly make periodic interpolation function using `ElementMeshInterpolation`.**

Answer (score 10):

You can not really. The fact that `Interpolation` can do this hinges on the data being structured. In other works what I am going to show next is not easily generally possible for meshes that represent a non rectangullar domain; which is the common case for FEM meshes.

You can hack it by using the `ExtrapolationHandler` option.

```
    Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
    data = Flatten[
       Table[{i, j, Sin[i + j]}, {i, 0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/50}, {j, 0, 
         2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/50}], 1];
    mesh = ToElementMesh[data[[;; , 1 ;; 2]]];
    f = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, data[[;; , -1]]];
```

Now, we can use `f` as a function in the extrapolation handler and map the coordinates outside the domain back onto `f`. This mapping back to the original domain is tricky to do generally. Here we use `Mod`.

```
    f2 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, data[[;; , -1]], 
      "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Function[{x, y}, 
         f[Mod[x, 2 \[Pi]], Mod[y, 2 \[Pi]]]]}]

{ContourPlot[f2[x, y], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
 ContourPlot[f2[x, y], {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 4 \[Pi]}]}
```

[image: plots]

If you want to switch of the warning message you can do so with:

```
f2 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, data[[;; , -1]], 
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Function[{x, y}, 
     f[Mod[x, 2 \[Pi]], Mod[y, 2 \[Pi]]]], "WarningMessage" -> False}]
```

Perhaps an idea for a future implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am interested in the overhead of "ExtrapolationHandler". I found a peculiar thing. The `ContourPlot` of f2 is even faster than f. However, `Table[Quiet@f2[x,y],{x,100.,150.,1},{y,100.,150.,1}];//AbsoluteTiming` is much slower than `Table[f[x,y],{x,100.,150.,1},{y,100.,150.,1}];//AbsoluteTiming`. Why is that?

Comment: And what do you mean by "Interpolation can do this hinges on the data being structured."

Comment: @matheorem, for your second question see update

Comment: @matheorem, here is a guess, If you are querying f outside it will have to generate an extrapolation value and it has to generate the Message. That might be the cost. If f2 is queried outside then you have the expense of the finding that the value is outside the domain plus the evaluation of f to get the value.

Comment: @matheorem, I have added this example to the documentation. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: I do not mind, of couse :)  Do you mean that `PeriodicInterpolation` does not support rectangular region? I actually need to interpolate on a parallelpiped region. I am thinking how to pull points outside region back by periodic condition. Do you have any good solution already exists in Mathematica?

Comment: About the timing. How to explain the ContourPlot of f2 is even faster than f?

Comment: `ElementMeshInterpolation` does not (can not in general) support `PeriodicInterpolation`. I don't know about the timing. I would have to take a closer look. Maybe `FindGeometricTansform` is useful.

Comment: I have a suggestion. I think If we have explicitly set `ExtrapolationHandler`, then "outside the range " warning message is redundent and should be removed internally, then we won't have to suppress the message which may cause performance issue

Comment: @matheorem, I'll file this as a suggestion. I can not do this immediately. Thanks. To switch if off now you can use `"ExtrapolationHandler" -> {..., "WarningMessage"->False}

Comment: When I do this: `{AbsoluteTiming[
  ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 4 \[Pi]}]], 
 AbsoluteTiming[
  ContourPlot[f2[x, y], {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 4 \[Pi]}]],
 AbsoluteTiming[
  ContourPlot[f3[x, y], {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 4 \[Pi]}]]}` I do not see any difference between f2 and f3. So the warning message may not be as expensive as I thought it was.

Comment: You are right. I did timing again, it seems fine now. Maybe I mixed up something previously. "WarningMessage"->False is great, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Since currently `ElementMeshInterpolation` does not support `PeriodicInterpolation` and `Interpolation` only support `PeriodicInterpolation` on rectangular grid. Apart from user21's workaround, I developed a workaround for arbitrary parallel or parallelipiped grid periodic interpolation.

The idea is naive, just to pull back points outside region by base vectors. Below is helper function.

```
pullBack2Dcom=Compile[{x1,x2,y1,y2,x,y},Mod[{(-x2 y+x y2)/(-x2 y1+x1 y2),(x1 y-x y1)/(-x2 y1+x1 y2)},1].{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}];
pullBack3Dcom=Compile[{x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3,x,y,z},Mod[{(x3 y2 z-x2 y3 z-x3 y z2+x y3 z2+x2 y z3-x y2 z3)/(x3 y2 z1-x2 y3 z1-x3 y1 z2+x1 y3 z2+x2 y1 z3-x1 y2 z3),(x3 y1 z-x1 y3 z-x3 y z1+x y3 z1+x1 y z3-x y1 z3)/(-x3 y2 z1+x2 y3 z1+x3 y1 z2-x1 y3 z2-x2 y1 z3+x1 y2 z3),(x2 y1 z-x1 y2 z-x2 y z1+x y2 z1+x1 y z2-x y1 z2)/(x3 y2 z1-x2 y3 z1-x3 y1 z2+x1 y3 z2+x2 y1 z3-x1 y2 z3)},1].{{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3,z3}}];
pullBack2D[{{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_}},{x_,y_}]:=pullBack2Dcom[x1,x2,y1,y2,x,y];
pullBack3D[{{x1_,y1_,z1_},{x2_,y2_,z2_},{x3_,y3_,z3_}},{x_,y_,z_}]:=pullBack3Dcom[x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3,x,y,z];
```

The expressions above seems complicated, but they are just solution of `LinearSolve` plus using `Mod` function.

Now I prepare a parallel grid data set which has periodic boundary condition.

```
data=N@Flatten[Table[Append[i{1,0}+j*{1,1},Sin[Total[i{1,0}+j*{1,1}]*2*\[Pi]]],{i,0,1.,1/100},{j,0,1.,1/100}],1];
ListContourPlot[data,AspectRatio->Automatic]
```

which gives

[image]

and then do mesh interpolation like below

```
mesh=ToElementMesh[data[[;;,1;;2]]];
f=ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh},data[[;;,-1]]];
ContourPlot[f[x,y],{x,y}\[Element]ConvexHullMesh[data[[;;,1;;2]]],AspectRatio->Automatic]
```

gives

[image]

which is good.

Now we can use `pullBack2D` to generate a periodic function using base vector `bvecs`

```
bvecs = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := f @@ pullBack2D[bvecs, {x, y}]
```

plot it using

```
ContourPlot[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

we get

[image]

Comment: You should be able to use a technique like the one [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159096) if you have the basis vectors of your "fundamental parallelogram".

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for the link. I see you use `LinearSolve` and that is exactly what I use except that I use the explict symbolic solution of `LinearSolve` to use `Compile`. I found `Compile` is much faster :)